# How to use zabbix agent to start windows process? (notepad.exe Or java.exe)?

Tags: zabbix, windows-shell

I set up a remote script (winodws shell) in zabbix actions,but it doesn't really execute(notepad does not appear). I don't know where the problem is? 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how can i set zabbix acitons for restart windows process(notepad++.exe or java.exe)？

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix agent does not run software in your current user session. It runs them in the background. Most likely, the command was executed just fine, just that it didn't do anything permanent. Instead, try to write something to a file or a similar test.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed it to be successful after modifying the file. But I also want to ask, if  want it to complete the restart "java.exe" can be achieved?@Richlv

Comment: What would be best asked as a new question, as it is different enough.